# Looking for an on-premise agile project management software

Tags: windows, project-management

I am looking for recommendations for an agile project management tool that is on-premise. Due to security requirements we cannot use online solutions. Besides this the tool should:

•   Support Agile (Scrum, Kanban, Scrumban, etc.)
•   Support multiple levels of tasks and subtasks
•   Have unlimited number of projects
•   Have time tracking
•   Integrate with MS Outlook
•   Integrate with TFS (ideally)

Answer (score 4):

If you are a Windows user, [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/) could be a good option. It is an agile on-premise solution that supports TFS and Outlook integrations. My team especially likes the visual drag&drop task board that is really easy to use.

Regarding your requirements, you will find various agile templates, the number of projects, tasks and subtasks is unlimited regardless of the subscription level and the time tracking is there, as well as some reporting capabilities.

[image]

Comment: If you are working for Eylean could you disclose it?

Comment: You could also consider looking at https://teamhood.com which is similar to Eylean's scrumban/Kanban approahc but Teamhood is cloud based

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a PM software with an Outlook integration, I'd recommend [InLoox](https://www.inloox.com/products/inloox-pm/inloox-pm-for-outlook/) Project Management Software. It has an on-premise version and their support team is really great and will assist all the way. I once had an issue with the budget generator and they fixed it almost immediately.

I have yet to find another PM software that is that seamlessly integrated into Outlook.

Here’s an overview of InLoox features: 
-   Supports agile, incl. Kanban board
-   Time tracking
-   Add recurring tasks
-   Custom notifications
-   Gantt chart (which means that you can use agile but can also combine it with  traditional PM if needed)
-   Document management
-   Dashboards
-   Budget planning and report generator